# Adjective after "to be" verb

Tags: verbs, adjectives

I have observed some sentences where past participle like "**to be delivered" or "to be given"** was used  after the verb "to be", however, today I have observed a sentence given below where sentence maker has not used past participle form of verb but used the normal word like **"out"** instead.

**Rajnath gets stuck in lift, scales wall to be out.**

Can anyone clarify, are these all (delivered, given, out) **Adjectives**? Meaning that it is **mandatory** to use an Adjective after "to be".

Thanks,

Charmi

Comment: I assumed this was a news headline, and yes it is: https://www.google.com/search?q=Rajnath+gets+stuck+in+lift%2C+scales+wall+to+be+out.&rlz=1C1PRFE_enIR614IR614&oq=Rajnath+gets+stuck+in+lift%2C+scales+wall+to+be+out.&aqs=chrome..69i57.200j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8 The important thing to consider here is that newspaper headlines use a different *theme* of English than standard English does. Non-standard grammar I mean. More info [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/newspaper-headlines).

Comment: To Charmi Sapariya (the OP), is your question about why it wasn't *"scales wall out"* instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**be** is a copular verb and it's used to connect the subject of the sentence to the complement - *a subject complement*.

> 1. The solution is easy.
> 2. The order will be delivered soon.
> 3. He is a policeman.

In the above sentences the verb **be** connects the subject to its complement. A complement need not be an adjective only, but anything that says something about the subject.

In sentence #1 the complement is an adjective. In sentence #2, the complement is past participle of verb (or can be viewed as an adjective), but in sentence #3 the complement is a noun phrase.

All these complements say something about the subjects. And hence they are called subject complement. A copular verb is the one that links the subject with its complement.

In your quoted sentence the complement is - **to be out**. This is an infinitive clause denoting the purpose of his **scaling**. **out** here is an adverbial modifying the verb **be** and referring to the position of the subject.

> Rajnath gets stuck in lift, scales wall to be out.

Scales the wall so that Rajnath comes out.

Answer (score 1):

In AmE, we would not say "scales wall to **be** out"; we would say "scales wall to **get** out". So the question about "to be" in this sense would never arise. Using stative "to be" in a context of vigorous effort (scaling a wall) baffles me.

Comment: Will it be better if we say **scales wall out** as Damkerng suggested in the comment? In that case I think the issue of *static* will be removed.

Comment: Well, "scales wall out" sounds incomplete to me, but I am, you know, American. And if it's a headline, space is very limited, so they often do not follow the syntax conventions that normal writing does.

Comment: Oh normally it's incomplete? What about **scale out the wall**?

Comment: That's worse. "Scale out the wall" almost sounds like making the wall bigger (larger-scale).

Comment: By the way, the _out_ in _to be out_ is indeed an adjective, but the _out_ in _to get out_ is an adverb. So we have so far sidestepped OP's question about adjectives, while fixing the bad example.

Comment: If you don't like "to get out" (or if Indian English doesn't use that construction), try "escapes by scaling wall".

Comment: No obviously **to get out** is common here. I am trying to consider the OP's sentences only :-)